# Prove that ℤ/nℤ is a field- prove closed under addition

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I have been asked to prove the following:

Let $\mathbb{F}_n$ = {[0],[1],...,[n-1]} be an $n$ point set, where $n$ is a positive integer. We impose addition and multiplication as follows:

$$[a] + [b] = [a + b],  [a] * [b] = [ab]$$

where $[x] = [y]$ iff $n$ divides $(x-y)$.

i) Prove that $\mathbb{F}_n$ is a field when $n$ is a prime number.

Right now, I am working on proving that addition is closed. I am kind of uncomfortable with my work so far and any guidance or verification would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far:

Closed under addition:

Let $a = nx, b = ny$ where $a,b \in n\mathbb{Z}, x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n$ is prime.

$$[a] + [b]$$

$$= [nx] + [ny]$$

$$= [nx + ny]$$

$$=[n(x+y)]$$

$$n(x+y) = z \ \bmod n,$$ by definition of $[n(x+y)].$

$$z = nj + n(x+y),$$ by division algorithm.

$$z = n(j+x+y)$$

By definition, $n\mid z$, so $[a + b] \in n\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: How do you define addition in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$? Also, do you know MathJax?

Comment: @agra94 Note: $n$ being a prime is necessary for $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to be a field, but not for the specific property of being closed under modular addition.

Comment: Apparently I don't know MathJax well enough haha. We weren't really given a precise definition of addition in ℤ/nℤ, but since we are supposed to show that it is a field I think my professor just wants us to show that the set is closed under addition @Mastrem

Comment: @57Jimmy, Wait, I'm confused. For a set to be a field, we are supposed to show that addition exists on the set, no? Doesn't this mean that we need to show that addition is closed?

Comment: It's not possible to prove something like this without a precise definition of the set $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and the operation $+$ on it.

Comment: @EricWofsey Just updated to show what our professor gave us for a definition of ℤ/nℤ and the operation + on it.

Comment: @agra94 Sure, you need to show it. But it's not the only thing that has to be shown. And for this specific thing you don't need $n$ to be prime. But you need it to show that every non-zero element is multiplicatively invertible, which is also necessary for a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're confused about what set you're talking about.  The set you want to show is closed under addition is $\mathbb{F}_n$, not $n\mathbb{Z}$.  So you want to start with arbitrary $[a],[b]\in\mathbb{F}_n$ (so, according to your definition of $\mathbb{F}_n$, $a$ and $b$ are integers between $0$ and $n-1$ inclusive).  Then you want to show $[a]+[b]=[a+b]$ is also an element of $\mathbb{F}_n$.  Again, according to your definition of $\mathbb{F}_n$, this means you need to show there is some integer $c$ between $0$ and $n-1$ such that $[c]=[a+b]$.

(Incidentally, you should probably also show that addition is *well-defined*: in other words, that there is *only one* $c$ between $0$ and $n-1$ such that $[c]=[a+b]$.  Otherwise, the given definition of "$[a]+[b]$" may not describe a unique element of $\mathbb{F}_n$.  That may be something you are allowed to assume as known, though.  In fact, you may be allowed to assume as known that addition and multiplication are binary operations on the set $\mathbb{F}_n$, so you do not have to prove closure or well-definedness at all.)

Comment: Hmm. I guess I'm confused. If we are talking about equivalence classes, I thought that there can be more than one "c" that satisfies [a+b]. For example, if n=5, then [3+4] = [7] = [2], ie that [a+b] = [c] is not unique. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, your definition of the set $\mathbb{F}_n$ was rather imprecise.  I took it to mean that you are defining $[a]$ as a purely formal symbol for each $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, and letting $[0],\dots,[n-1]$ represent the $n$ elements of your chosen "$n$ point set".  For this to make sense, you need the formal symbols $[0],\dots,[n-1]$ to be distinct from each other.

Comment: If you are _first_ defining the symbols $[a]$ as equivalence classes and defining $\mathbb{F}_n=\{[0],\dots,[n-1]\}$, then you do not have to prove the uniqueness of $[c]$.  (However, in that case, it is not immediate that $\mathbb{F}_n$ actually has $n$ points as you claimed.)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure honestly. It may be a typo in the assignment provided by my professor.

Comment: Anyway, I am working on my proof. Instead I have now that a=x mod n, b= y mod n. [a] + [b] = [a+b] = [x mod n + y mod n] = [(x+y)modn]. I am not sure what to do at this point. Originally I tried to do that (x+y)mod n = z mod n, but I couldn't really figure out a way out of this. Am I on the right track? Is there something that I am missing? I guess I'm trying to develop some intuition for this but am obviously struggling. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "x mod n".  Where did x come from?  Literally all you have to prove is that there exists $c$ between $0$ and $n-1$ such that $[a+b]=[c]$.  According to your definition of $[x]=[y]$, what does this mean?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to define an [a] and [b] in the set of Fn. In this case [a] = x mod n, where x = some integer and n = some prime, and a is its remainder. I guess I was trying to prove it a different way. I understand what you are saying now. if [x] = [y], and we let a+b = x and y = c, then [a+b] = [c] if n|(a+b-c). Then, n|(a+b-a-b) => n|(0). n|0 holds for all values of n, and [0] is contained within Fn. So, we have shown closure....right?

Comment: No, you haven't proved anything.  You never defined what $c$ is.  You need to prove that there _exists_ $c$ between $0$ and $n-1$ so that this is true, so that $[c]$ (and therefore $[a+b]$) is an element of $\mathbb{F}_n$.

Comment: Okay, what if I say that c = a + b.

Comment: That's a good idea...but what if $a+b$ is not between $0$ and $n-1$?

Comment: Well it doesn't really matter, right, as long as [a+b] is between [0] and [n-1]. Right?

Comment: I don't know what it means for $[a+b]$ to be between $[0]$ and $[n-1]$.  If by that you mean that $[a+b]=[c]$ for some $c$ between $0$ and $n-1$, you have just rephrased what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Sigh. Yes I did do that because I am dumb. Hmm, okay I think I know what you're saying now. If a + b = c is not between 0 and n-1 it doesn't matter as long as n|([c-y]), where y is between 0 and n-1? I feel like I'm talking in circles kind of.

Comment: Right.  Can you prove that such a $y$ exists?

Answer (score 0):

For every two residue classes, $\overline{a},\overline{b}\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, we can pick representatives in $\mathbb{Z}$, say $a$ and $b$. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed under addition, $a+b$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}$. Since $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is literally what we get when partitioning $\mathbb{Z}$ using the equivalence relation
$$a\sim b\iff a\equiv b\pmod n,$$
we know that $a+b$ is an element of exacly one residue class, so $\overline{a+b}$ is a well-defined element of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

---

Of course this assumes you've already proven that addition 
$$\overline{a}+\overline{b}=\overline{a+b}$$
is well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

Say $(a+b)\cong z \pmod n$...  Now say $a\cong x \pmod n$ and $b \cong y \pmod n$.

It is easy to see $x+y \cong z \pmod n$.

Namely, $\exists k,l,m \in \mathbb  Z: (a+b)=z+k\cdot n, a=x+l\cdot n \text { and } b=y+m\cdot n$...

Now $a+b=(x+y)+(l+m)\cdot n \implies z+k\cdot n=(x+y)+ (l+m)\cdot n \implies z-(x+y)=(l+m-k)\cdot n$...  Of course, $l+m-k\in \mathbb Z$...  So $x+y\cong z \pmod n$...

Comment: Thank you!! This is the proof I started getting at in the comments below, although I stupidly did [x modn] which makes no sense. Instead I have now that [a]=x mod n, [b]= y mod n. [a] + [b] = [a+b] = x mod n + y mod n = (x+y)modn. z = nj + n(x+y). So, z = n(j+x+y). I am not sure what to do at this point. Am I on the right track? Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: I believe it's well-definedness we are actually proving...

Comment: I attempted to write it out carefully so you could follow...  (you were on the same track, until the last step...  you showed $z\cong 0 \pmod n$...  you want $z\cong (x+y) \pmod n$...  where $z=(a+b) \pmod n$...